# Where does the repulsive force come from in this force based layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, force-layout

In this block by Mike Bostock when you move the mouse the nodes are pushed away. From the code in the example I don't understand how that's happening.

I see that a node has been removed from the nodes array after they layout is generated, its fixed property is set to true, and that its position gets updated based on mouse movement, and it is not acted upon during ticks. But there is never any force assigned to it.

It looks like the force is magically created or somehow inferred. What's going on here?

```js
var width = 640,
    height = 480,
    τ = 2 * Math.PI,
    gravity = .05;

var sample = poissonDiscSampler(width, height, 30),
    nodes = [{x: 0, y: 0}],
    s;

while (s = sample()) nodes.push(s);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes.slice())
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? -30 : -3000; })
    .on("tick", ticked)
    .start();

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

var root = nodes.shift();

root.fixed = true;

var links = voronoi.links(nodes);

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("ontouchstart" in document ? "touchmove" : "mousemove", moved);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

function moved() {
  var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
  root.px = p1[0];
  root.py = p1[1];
  force.resume();
}

function ticked() {
  force.resume();

  for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    node.y += (node.cy - node.y) * gravity;
    node.x += (node.cx - node.x) * gravity;
  }

  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  context.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0, n = links.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var link = links[i];
    context.moveTo(link.source.x, link.source.y);
    context.lineTo(link.target.x, link.target.y);
  }
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = "#bbb";
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    context.moveTo(node.x, node.y);
    context.arc(node.x, node.y, 2, 0, τ);
  }
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  context.fill();
}

// Based on https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/
function poissonDiscSampler(width, height, radius) {
  var k = 30, // maximum number of samples before rejection
      radius2 = radius * radius,
      R = 3 * radius2,
      cellSize = radius * Math.SQRT1_2,
      gridWidth = Math.ceil(width / cellSize),
      gridHeight = Math.ceil(height / cellSize),
      grid = new Array(gridWidth * gridHeight),
      queue = [],
      queueSize = 0,
      sampleSize = 0;

  return function() {
    if (!sampleSize) return sample(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);

    // Pick a random existing sample and remove it from the queue.
    while (queueSize) {
      var i = Math.random() * queueSize | 0,
          s = queue[i];

      // Make a new candidate between [radius, 2 * radius] from the existing sample.
      for (var j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        var a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random(),
            r = Math.sqrt(Math.random() * R + radius2),
            x = s.x + r * Math.cos(a),
            y = s.y + r * Math.sin(a);

        // Reject candidates that are outside the allowed extent,
        // or closer than 2 * radius to any existing sample.
        if (0 <= x && x < width && 0 <= y && y < height && far(x, y)) return sample(x, y);
      }

      queue[i] = queue[--queueSize];
      queue.length = queueSize;
    }
  };

  function far(x, y) {
    var i = x / cellSize | 0,
        j = y / cellSize | 0,
        i0 = Math.max(i - 2, 0),
        j0 = Math.max(j - 2, 0),
        i1 = Math.min(i + 3, gridWidth),
        j1 = Math.min(j + 3, gridHeight);

    for (j = j0; j < j1; ++j) {
      var o = j * gridWidth;
      for (i = i0; i < i1; ++i) {
        if (s = grid[o + i]) {
          var s,
              dx = s.x - x,
              dy = s.y - y;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius2) return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  function sample(x, y) {
    var s = {x: x, y: y, cx: x, cy: y};
    queue.push(s);
    grid[gridWidth * (y / cellSize | 0) + (x / cellSize | 0)] = s;
    ++sampleSize;
    ++queueSize;
    return s;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, there is no *magic* here. This is the line you have to look at, in the `d3.layout.force()`:

```
.charge(function(d, i) { return i ? -30 : -3000; })
```

What it says is basically this:

> Apply a charge of -30 to each node, unless it is the first one. In that case, apply a charge of -3000.

Why?

That's a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It will evaluate a condition. If the condition is true, it will execute the first expression, if it is false it will execute the second one.

In JavaScript, `0` is falsy, while all other positive integers are, of course, truthy. Since that `i` is the index, only the first index (when `i` is `0`) will evaluate to false. All other indices will evaluate to true.

So, for the first index, we have:

```
return false ? -30 : -3000;
//this will return -3000
```

While for all other indices we have:

```
return true ? -30 : -3000;
//this will return -30
```

We can clearly see this in the following snippet, where I changed -3000 to +3000. Now, the first node (where the cursor is) will chaotically attract instead of repel:

```js
var width = 640,
    height = 480,
    τ = 2 * Math.PI,
    gravity = .05;

var sample = poissonDiscSampler(width, height, 30),
    nodes = [{x: 0, y: 0}],
    s;

while (s = sample()) nodes.push(s);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .nodes(nodes.slice())
    .gravity(0)
    .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? -30 : +3000; })
    .on("tick", ticked)
    .start();

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; });

var root = nodes.shift();

root.fixed = true;

var links = voronoi.links(nodes);

var canvas = d3.select("body").append("canvas")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("ontouchstart" in document ? "touchmove" : "mousemove", moved);

var context = canvas.node().getContext("2d");

function moved() {
  var p1 = d3.mouse(this);
  root.px = p1[0];
  root.py = p1[1];
  force.resume();
}

function ticked() {
  force.resume();

  for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    node.y += (node.cy - node.y) * gravity;
    node.x += (node.cx - node.x) * gravity;
  }

  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  context.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0, n = links.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var link = links[i];
    context.moveTo(link.source.x, link.source.y);
    context.lineTo(link.target.x, link.target.y);
  }
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = "#bbb";
  context.stroke();

  context.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0, n = nodes.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    context.moveTo(node.x, node.y);
    context.arc(node.x, node.y, 2, 0, τ);
  }
  context.lineWidth = 3;
  context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = "#000";
  context.fill();
}

// Based on https://www.jasondavies.com/poisson-disc/
function poissonDiscSampler(width, height, radius) {
  var k = 30, // maximum number of samples before rejection
      radius2 = radius * radius,
      R = 3 * radius2,
      cellSize = radius * Math.SQRT1_2,
      gridWidth = Math.ceil(width / cellSize),
      gridHeight = Math.ceil(height / cellSize),
      grid = new Array(gridWidth * gridHeight),
      queue = [],
      queueSize = 0,
      sampleSize = 0;

  return function() {
    if (!sampleSize) return sample(Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height);

    // Pick a random existing sample and remove it from the queue.
    while (queueSize) {
      var i = Math.random() * queueSize | 0,
          s = queue[i];

      // Make a new candidate between [radius, 2 * radius] from the existing sample.
      for (var j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
        var a = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random(),
            r = Math.sqrt(Math.random() * R + radius2),
            x = s.x + r * Math.cos(a),
            y = s.y + r * Math.sin(a);

        // Reject candidates that are outside the allowed extent,
        // or closer than 2 * radius to any existing sample.
        if (0 <= x && x < width && 0 <= y && y < height && far(x, y)) return sample(x, y);
      }

      queue[i] = queue[--queueSize];
      queue.length = queueSize;
    }
  };

  function far(x, y) {
    var i = x / cellSize | 0,
        j = y / cellSize | 0,
        i0 = Math.max(i - 2, 0),
        j0 = Math.max(j - 2, 0),
        i1 = Math.min(i + 3, gridWidth),
        j1 = Math.min(j + 3, gridHeight);

    for (j = j0; j < j1; ++j) {
      var o = j * gridWidth;
      for (i = i0; i < i1; ++i) {
        if (s = grid[o + i]) {
          var s,
              dx = s.x - x,
              dy = s.y - y;
          if (dx * dx + dy * dy < radius2) return false;
        }
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

  function sample(x, y) {
    var s = {x: x, y: y, cx: x, cy: y};
    queue.push(s);
    grid[gridWidth * (y / cellSize | 0) + (x / cellSize | 0)] = s;
    ++sampleSize;
    ++queueSize;
    return s;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```